# How to get left part of path in python?

Tags: python, path

How can I get the most left part of relative path in python?

I started with something like this:

```
/var/tmp/workdir/1/foo/bar/test.jpg
```

Then I removed some of it to get:

```
1/foo/bar/test.jpg
```

Using:

```
rel_path = os.path.relpath(path,base_dir)
```

Now how can I get the most left part - the "1" ?

I can only find tools that go from the right side, but in this case I want the most left thing because it correspondents with a user ID. Also I want to avoid going from the right side, because there might be more sub directories.

Comment: You can use regular expression or if the id is always on the same place you can split by '/' and get the wanted element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `str.split` might give incorrect results if names contain `os.path.sep` (escaped of course). The safest solution imho is:

```
basename = None # guards against UnboundLocalError in case of empty rel_path
while rel_path:
    rel_path, basename = os.path.split(rel_path)
print basename # this will be the leftmost component
```

Comment: I understand that the least thing I want to do is use split commands to manually get the first part. But why is there no command to just get the first part? I guess your approach will do, but it's a waste of cpu isn't it?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about cpu: `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.39 µs per loop`. Unless you are expecting to parse thousands of paths pers second, each hundreds of components...

Answer (score 2):

poke mentioned the pathlib library that's built into Python 3.4. You can also use pathlib on Python 2.6 or 2.7 by running `pip install pathlib`, as stated here: http://pathlib.readthedocs.org/en/pep428.

Your code would look like this:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath
>>> p = PurePath('1/foo/bar/test.jpg')
>>> p.parts
('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'test.jpg')
```

And use `p.parts[0]` to get the part you want.

In fact, you could do the whole thing with pathlib as follows:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath
>>> p = PurePath('/var/tmp/workdir/1/foo/bar/test.jpg')
>>> p = p.relative_to('/var/tmp/workdir')
>>> p.parts
('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'test.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this, too. But I think for now I will go with the while loop, because this way I don't need extra libraries. But if I encounter more of that I will switch to your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3.4, you could use the new [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts) for this.

Otherwise, you could just use normal string manipulation to get that part, for example with [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> path = '1/foo/bar/test.jpg'
>>> path.partition('/')
('1', '/', 'foo/bar/test.jpg')
```

You could also use [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) instead of `'/'` if you want to split on the operating system’s path separator.